# Using Google Sheets API to GET multiple Spreadsheets

Tags: php, google-sheets

Using PHP, would anyone happen to know how to use a folder/directory URL to retrieve all of the Google Spreadsheets inside of that particular folder? Not to be confused with getting all of the sheets inside of a spreadsheet.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Review [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer. Because Google Drive manages the directories which stores the Sheets, Google Drive API (specifically listing "children") retrieves all files within a folder. Thank you.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list